# Determine if Parent is an Activity or FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a custom widget saved as an android library project.
The custom widget uses Fragments and so needs to access the Application's FragmentManager.

I would like my custom widget to be compatible with Applications that extend Activity (Honeycomb or higher) and also  Applications that extend FragmentActivity.

To achieve this I need my custom widget to decide whether to use `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()` based on whether the parent extends Activity or FragmentActivity as shown below.

```
switch (getApplicationType()) {
case ACTIVITY__HONEYCOMB_ONWARD
    FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)getContext()).getFragmentManager();
    //...
    break;
case FRAGMENT_ACTIVITY
    FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
    //...
    break;
//...
```

The bit that has me stumped is how to write the tests in my getApplicationType() method.

```
private int getApplicationType() {
    if (??? How do I write this test ???) {
        return ACTIVITY__HONEYCOMB_ONWARD;
    } else if (??? How do I write this test ???) {
        return FRAGMENT_ACTIVITY;
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `instanceof`.

For example:

```
if ( getParent() instanceof Activity ) {
   return ACTIVITY;
} else if ( getParent() instanceof Fragment ) {
   return FRAGMENT;
} etc…
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! I'd been trying something along the lines of (getContext() == Activity.Class) and obviously got nowhere.